# Logstash - how to parse nested JSON turning each nested object into an event?

Tags: json, logstash

So, I'm trying to configure logstash to fetch JSON data from a public API and insert into Elasticsearch.

The data looks like this:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Aggregation",
        "2. Name": "EXAMPLE",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-04-06"
    },
    "Time Series": {
        "2018-04-06": {
            "1. Value1": "20",
            "2. Value 2": "21",
            "3. Value 3": "20",
            "4. Value 4": "21",
            "5. Value 5": "47"
        },
        "2018-04-05": {
            "1. open": "21",
            "2. high": "21",
            "3. low": "21",
            "4. close": "21",
            "5. volume": "88"
        },
        "2018-04-04": {
            "1. open": "20",
            "2. high": "20",
            "3. low": "20",
            "4. close": "20",
            "5. volume": "58"
        },
        "2018-04-03": {
            "1. Value1": "20",
            "2. Value 2": "21",
            "3. Value 3": "20",
            "4. Value 4": "21",
            "5. Value 5": "47"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't care about the metadata, I want each object inside the "Time Series" to become a different event to be sent to Elasticsearch. I just don't know how to do it.

So far, I just got the input configuration right...

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
        test1 => "https://www.public-facing-api.com/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&name=EXAMPLE"
        #headers => {
        #   Accept => "application/json"
        #}
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    # Supports "cron", "every", "at" and "in" schedules by rufus scheduler
    schedule => { cron => "* * * * * * UTC"}
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        target => "parsedMain"
    }
    json {
        source => "[parsedMain][Time Series]"
        target => "parsedContent"
    }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But it just prints everything as a single object.

I would also like to capture the date, which is the name of each nested object, and set it to ES timestamp. Also, the id as %{date}_%{name}.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you'll need a ruby filter + a split filter.  You need to turn the `Time Series` hash into an array and then split on the array:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    ruby {
        code => '
            arrayOfEvents = Array.new()
            ts = event.get("Time Series")
            ts.each do |date,data|
                data["date"]=date # set the date on the sub-object, since we likely need that
                arrayOfEvents.push(data)
            end
            event.set("event",arrayOfEvents)
        '
        remove_field => ["Time Series","Meta Data" ]
    }
    split {
        field => 'event'
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Example out output:

```
...
{
    "@timestamp" => 2018-04-09T15:01:01.765Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxx.local",
          "type" => "yyyyy",
         "event" => {
              "date" => "2018-04-03",
         "1. Value1" => "20",
        "5. Value 5" => "47",
        "3. Value 3" => "20",
        "4. Value 4" => "21",
        "2. Value 2" => "21"
    }
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2018-04-09T15:01:01.765Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxx.local",
          "type" => "yyyyy",
         "event" => {
           "3. low" => "20",
             "date" => "2018-04-04",
        "5. volume" => "58",
          "1. open" => "20",
          "2. high" => "20",
         "4. close" => "20"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is spot on.